# Download canvas as image in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I want to download the canvas as an image when clicked on the button. But Im getting errors denoting "canvas1 is null" but it doesn't make sense to me.

This is my canvas component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Canvas = ({ draw, height, width }) => {
  const canvas = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    draw(context);
  });

  function download(){
    let canvas1 = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    let url = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'filename.png';
    link.href = url;
    link.click();
  }

  return (
  <>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" ref={canvas} height={height} width={width} />;
<div className="div">
<button onclick={download()}>Download!</button>
</div>
  </>
  )
};

Canvas.propTypes = {
  draw: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  width: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

export default Canvas;
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: `onclick={download}` or `onclick={() => download()}`

Comment: Btw, you should use ref instead of `getElementById`

Comment: As well as the point Konrad raised (you're currently assigning the result of calling the download function to the listener rather than the actual function reference), since you've already attached a ref to the canvas element it should be `let canvas1 = canvas.current;`. (Note: it might be a good idea to call your `ref` `canvasRef` so as to distinguish it from the actual canvas.)

Comment: @Konrad yes I didnt notice that. now the error is gone but im getting "Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure." when clicking the button

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cloud-zn41dg?file=/src/canvas.js

Comment: what im trying to do is that , rendering an image onto canvas and download it. so im able to download the canvas before image loads but after its showing this error